# Is it possible to lock the mouse inside a FULLSCREEN flash application (multiple monitors)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mouse, multiple-monitors

I've done some research and determined that it isn't currently possible to lock the mouse into a flash application/game. People keep suggesting using fullscreen mode, which is great for a single monitor solution.

However, I am developing applications that use 2 or more monitors, and require the mouse to be restricted to certain ones.

**Is it possible, when running flash in full screen mode, to restrict the mouse to staying inside the full screen app, so that it can't move to and click on other monitors?**

I am using AS3.
I am also running these flash applications in Adobe AIR, if that makes any difference.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Funny how you ask this just after this feature (mouse-locking) was announced ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature will not be available until Flash Player 11.2 is released. You can check out this video for a demo: http://www.bytearray.org/?p=3732

This post has the same video, but a little bit of description as well: http://www.leebrimelow.com/?p=3133